# mvc4 bind @Html.DropDownListFor in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

How to bind a @Html.DropDownListFor to the value that comes from the model?
my model:

```
public UpdatePersonalModel()
{
  Titles = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
  Titles.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Mr",Value = "Mr"});
  Titles.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Mrs",Value = "Mrs"});
  Titles.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Miss",Value = "Miss"});
  Titles.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Ms",Value = "Ms"});
  Titles.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Dr",Value = "Dr"});
  Titles.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Hon",Value = "Hon"});
  Titles.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Prof",Value = "Prof"});
}
public List<SelectListItem> Titles { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
...
...
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdatePersonal()
{
    //...
    var model = new UpdatePersonalModel();
    model.Title = webContext.CurrentUser.Title;
    model.FirstName = webContext.CurrentUser.First_Name;
    model.MiddleName = webContext.CurrentUser.q_Middle_Name;
    //...

    return View(model);
}
```

in the view:
When I have the model.Title is brings up the model value but it duplicate the value and does not bind
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.Titles, Model.Title,new { @class = "EnrtyFeildSelect" })` here it always bring the first value
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.Titles, new { @class = "EnrtyFeildSelect" })`

Comment: the second way is the correct way.  If you set Title before sent to the view does the correct value set?  does that value get passed back to the controller?

Comment: No, That is the problem. the ddl always set to the first value not the one I pass in the controller.

Comment: it shouldn't matter but try changing the value to a number instead of a string and see if that makes a difference.  Also try setting the selected property of one of your select list items and see if that selected makes it to the view